# How to Edit Fragment Content in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have been struggling with creating a `ViewPager` in *Android Studio* for quite some time, but I just realised that you can create one automatically by using a pre-configured `Activity`.

Having created a `Tabbed Activity`: `Action Bar Tabs` with `ViewPager`, I ended up with two XML layouts: `activity_main.xml` and `fragment_main.xml`. However, I am not sure how to change each fragment independently. Whenever I add a `TextView` in `fragment_main.xml`, it appears on all three pre-defined sections.

How do I change one section without affecting the other two?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). This will show you how to create tabs using `ViewPager`. In particular, you will need an `PagerAdapter` which is responsible for creating the correct fragment for each tab.

Answer (score -1):

In the method  getItem(int position)  in  FragmentPagerAdapter,this line PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1) decides which fragment it returns.
There is only one type of Fragment and the returned fragments have the same layout,but in PlaceholderFragment you can change it's layout according to position,example:

```
 /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    private int mPosition;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

    }
    private View mRootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        switch (mPosition) {
            case 0:
                 mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_0, container, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                 mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_1, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
               mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_2, container, false);
                break;
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return mRootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that all Java code must be inside a class.

Comment: Also, this is most properly done with a `PagerAdapter` and multiple `Fragment` subclasses, one for each layout.